# Copy from vim (putty-session) to Windows clipboard

Tags: windows, vim, clipboard, putty

I can copy from my Putty-Console to my Windows-Clipboard except from `vim`.

So with the standard method I can copy/past from he console,  from `more`, `nano` and others but impossible to do the same from `vim` :(

The method I've used:

- Selecting text in `vim` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> in Windows application.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks how to use the clipboard with terminal emulators on Windows, unrelated to Unix & Linux.

Comment: @panki:  Politely allow me to disagree with you. More than a Windows problem seems to be a Vim problem. I have similar problems with VcXsrv X Server and Netbeans and Eclipse and I don´t think it has anything to do with Windows but I am running VcXsrv on Windows.

Comment: I think Vim is capturing your mouse. Try `:set mouse=` in Vim and see if that works. If that fixes it for you, just add that line to your `~/.vimrc`, you can omit the `:` when you add it to that file.

Comment: i've never had a problem copying out of putty and pasting into anything Windows.  Left click and highlight in putty, then Ctrl-V to paste into whatever in Microsoft Windows.  Mouse right click is typically paste when it's all within the putty window.  In putty whether it is in `vim` or some other program has never mattered for me, left click and highlighting any text within putty has been 100% reliable for me over however many years now.  from putty-0.67 to the current 0.74.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

here are the default settings in putty-0.74, that have been 100% reliable for me.

left click and highlight whatever within the putty window.

that which is highlighted is then available on the windows clipboard and will paste into any windows program with CTRL-V.

to paste back within the putty window, i've always just use the right mouse button.

Answer (score 1):

While using `vim` in a PuTTY session, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while selecting an area with the mouse. The selected area should then be in the windows clipboard and you can paste it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to any windows app.

Answer (score 0):

I use PuTTY with Vim to copy and paste from Vim to Windows very often and it works well. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> *to copy from Vim* and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> *to paste into Windows*.

If it only happens to you with Vim,  check your `$HOME/.vimrc` file.

This is what I have in mine and it works well:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
set hidden
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```